# Out Of Memory allocating 16400 bytes! Redis version 5.0.7

Tags: ubuntu, redis

Redis 5.0.7 start to crush 2 times a day.

No clue what is the problem.

Real dedicated server with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and redis_version:5.0.7

Do any one have any solution for this problem?

```
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # Out Of Memory allocating 16400 bytes!

=== REDIS BUG REPORT START: Cut & paste starting from here ===
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # ------------------------------------------------
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # !!! Software Failure. Press left mouse button to continue
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # Guru Meditation: Redis aborting for OUT OF MEMORY #server.c:3925
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # (forcing SIGSEGV in order to print the stack trace)
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # ------------------------------------------------

727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # Redis 5.0.7 crashed by signal: 11
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # Crashed running the instruction at: 0x558a3fb301d8
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.373 # Accessing address: 0xffffffffffffffff
727269:M 31 Jan 2022 00:30:02.374 # Failed assertion: <no assertion failed> (<no file>:0)

------ STACK TRACE ------
EIP:
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(_serverPanic+0x148)[0x558a3fb301d8]

Backtrace:
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(logStackTrace+0x4f)[0x558a3fb323af]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(sigsegvHandler+0xb5)[0x558a3fb32bb5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0)[0x7f9bae3ef3c0]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(_serverPanic+0x148)[0x558a3fb301d8]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(redisOutOfMemoryHandler+0x3a)[0x558a3fae833a]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(zmalloc+0x47)[0x558a3faf2227]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(+0x406a1)[0x558a3faf96a1]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(addReplyBulkCBuffer+0x2d)[0x558a3fafad3d]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(zrangeGenericCommand+0x49b)[0x558a3fb1be7b]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(call+0xaf)[0x558a3faeab2f]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(execCommand+0xa0)[0x558a3fb2f4c0]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(call+0xaf)[0x558a3faeab2f]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(processCommand+0x556)[0x558a3faeb436]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(processInputBuffer+0x171)[0x558a3fafc0a1]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(aeProcessEvents+0x112)[0x558a3fae42d2]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(aeMain+0x2b)[0x558a3fae46fb]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(main+0x4de)[0x558a3fadeade]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7f9bae20f0b3]
/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379(_start+0x2e)[0x558a3faded3e]

------ INFO OUTPUT ------
# Server
redis_version:5.0.7
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:636cde3b5c7a3923
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 5.4.0-91-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:9.2.1
process_id:727269
run_id:45becaec4768155c1d3c8271ead92e91cf9a70f3
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:166034
uptime_in_days:1
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:16199050
executable:/usr/bin/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:12
client_recent_max_input_buffer:2
client_recent_max_output_buffer:21242144
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:888212864
used_memory_human:847.07M
used_memory_rss:958337024
used_memory_rss_human:913.94M
used_memory_peak:997885080
used_memory_peak_human:951.66M
used_memory_peak_perc:89.01%
used_memory_overhead:13150728
used_memory_startup:796240
used_memory_dataset:875062136
used_memory_dataset_perc:98.61%
allocator_allocated:880644368
allocator_active:885395456
allocator_resident:958627840
total_system_memory:67335008256
total_system_memory_human:62.71G
used_memory_lua:41984
used_memory_lua_human:41.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.01
allocator_frag_bytes:4751088
allocator_rss_ratio:1.08
allocator_rss_bytes:73232384
rss_overhead_ratio:1.00
rss_overhead_bytes:-290816
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.09
mem_fragmentation_bytes:77898880
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:12287984
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.2.1
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:23650
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1643588969
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:4
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:25165824
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:13
total_commands_processed:102906626
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:926
total_net_input_bytes:8983249537
total_net_output_bytes:4435914469033
instantaneous_input_kbps:77.77
instantaneous_output_kbps:135559.84
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:6
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:1315761
keyspace_misses:290168
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:51277
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_replid:2eed69c763f620b59fca82d19dce867e77bebadd
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:0
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:2993.230513
used_cpu_user:12988.348760
used_cpu_sys_children:791.588198
used_cpu_user_children:8576.694524
```

Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache, and message broker. Redis provides data structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs, geospatial indexes, and streams. Redis has built-in replication, Lua scripting, LRU eviction, transactions, and different levels of on-disk persistence, and provides high availability via Redis Sentinel and automatic partitioning with Redis Cluster.